# Declare an array without allocating memory

Tags: c++, c, arrays

How do I declare an array without allocating memory. Usually we will do

```
int myArray[10];
printf("%p ", &myArray[0]); // this would print the address.
```

But this would allocate memory.

Is there anyway of doing this?

Comment: Can you provide a use-case? It's hard to see what you really mean/want/need...

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Address of what? If `myArray` is not allocated, you could not get its address!

Comment: Where do you expect the memory to come from?

Comment: @nneonneo If i print the address, I am getting 0013FF38

Comment: @Patil: and if it were not allocated...how would you get an address? What problem do you aim to solve by not allocating the array?

Comment: @Patil You need to explain what you are doing and why you ask the question. It doesn't make much sense yet.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I just want to know, how an array can be declared with out allocating memory to it. I executed the above code in VS, i got the answer printed as 0013FF38.

Comment: Saying the same thing over and again won't help. Try and explain the why. How will you use such a thing, if it were even possible to exist.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: In India, people ask this kind of idiotic questions in the interviews. I got this from one of the sample papers. Can't help!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
extern int myArray[10];
```

in any one of the `header file` and define the array like this

```
int myArray[10];    // you can also initialize here
```

in anyone of the `source file`.

By doing (say you have only 1 file)

```
extern int myArray[10];
int main(void)
{
    printf("%p ", &myArray[0]); 
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Linker will throw error "`Unresolved External Symbol`". Linker will search for the array to print its address, but there is no definition of the array is provided. So linker will throw the error.

Answer (score 2):

To explicitly declare something in the global scope you can use `extern`:

```
extern int myArray[10];
```

However, you will need to define it in some (read: exactly one) compilation unit.

Answer (score 0):

This is a silly question, every time you declare a data-type. You allocate memory to that variable. It isn't possible to allocate memory and use a variable without allocating memory to it.

Comment: No, every time you *define* a variable you allocate memory.  The word *declare* in C means simply to describe the variable's existence in enough detail that code which uses it can be compiled.